# PNG file to C array

Tags: c, png

I have a PNG file of a grey scale image, and I want to convert it into a double array in C.

For example, I want to convert this image:

[image]

into this array :

```
[1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
 1.,   0.,  0.894, 0.,   1.,
 0.573,0.,   0.,   0.,  0.573,
 1.,   0.,   1.,   0.,   1.,
 1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.,
 1.,   0.,  0.894, 0.,   1.,
 1.,   1.,  0.572, 1.,   1.]
```

How should I do this?

I tried to use python to convert my PNG to a CSV file, and then use *fopen* and *fgets* C functions.
I'm looking for a more efficient solution, only using C.

Comment: Use a library that handles PNG files for you.

Comment: 1. you cannot use `fgets` to use binary data. It's only for text data. 2. PNG images are encoded and it's quite complicated to decoded it, use a library.

Comment: You can use `libpng` to read directly. Or, you could use ImageMagick's `convert` program to convert it to a `.ppm` file. That format is easy to write code for. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit not straightforward, but if you mean what I understood - you need to find an online converter to any format you need (xpm for example), then allocate memory using malloc and fill it with info you need

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.
I want to collect the value of each pixels to use it on an algorithm I already wrote, that takes as input an array of double. I don't want to convert my PNG to an other image format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).